# Outlook not stacking TDs for desktop in html email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have an html email that works fine in everything except outlook.

I have td with content in them.

```
<td style="display: block;">
 <!-- content here -->
</td>
<td style="display: block;">
 <!-- content here -->
</td>
```

Then for mobile I switch them to display table-cell to make them inline.

My problem is with outlook, it doesn't understand my desktop desktop display: block rule. I've even tried using  instead, but it doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a weird and alternative responsive flow to the norm which is to have everything inline and then stack for mobile, however there are some techniques to try...

First is to utilise Outlook specific code to force the stack in Outlook.
Second is an alternative method, using floating (aligned) tables. I always find tables the best to work with in any case like this but running a quick test in Litmus showed the first option with table cells to work just fine in all big email clients.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:AllowPNG/><o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch></o:OfficeDocumentSettings></xml><![endif]-->

    <style>
        table, td, th { border-collapse:collapse; }

        @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            .stack-container { width:100%!important; }
            .stack-td { display:table-cell!important; }
            .stack-td-2 { width:50%!important; }
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body id="body" style="margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#FFFFFF">
        <table role="presentation" class="stack-container" style="width:500px; border:1px solid red;">
            <tr>
                <!--[if mso]>
                <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation">
                <tr>
                <![endif]-->
                <td class="stack-td" style="display:block; border:1px solid green;">nnn</td>
                <!--[if mso]>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <![endif]-->
                <td class="stack-td" style="display:block; border:1px solid green;">nnn</td>
                <!--[if mso]>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br />
        <br />

        <table role="presentation" class="stack-container" style="width:500px; border:1px solid red;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table align="left" role="presentation" class="stack-td-2" style="width:100%; border:1px solid red;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="display:block; border:1px solid green;">nnn</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table align="right" role="presentation" class="stack-td-2" style="width:100%; border:1px solid red;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="display:block; border:1px solid green;">nnn</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I feel the extra table (in Outlook conditional statement) can be removed. If you have only the code that make the row would work just fine 

Answer (score -2):

**Edit**: I missed the stack on desktop part. This will be seen only by Outlook 2007 and newer. It's exactly what I proposed before, only set to Outlook-only.

Force Outlook to stack using a custom Outlook-only  in the head to push the width to 100%. I suggest something like this:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><style>
  .stack-container {
     width: 100% !important;
     margin: auto !important;
  }
  .stack-td {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
</style><![endif]-->
```

Now for the table:

```
<table role="presentation" class="stack-container">
  <tr>
    <td class="stack-td"></td>
    <td class="stack-td"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I hope things stack up for you.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm trying to have it stack on desktop, not on mobile

Comment: I missed that part, but this code should work with a minor adjustment.